# MIPS & SPIM : Instruction references undefined symbol at 0x00400024

Tags: mips

I use the command *spim -file file.s* but I got the error : **Instruction references undefined symbol at 0x00400024** and I don't understand why that happened.

There is my code :

```
  .text
  .globl    main
main:
  lw $t0,temp2
  lw $t1, temp3
  add $t1,$t0,$t1
  sw $t0,temp4

  lw $t0,b
  lw $t1,temp5
  sub $t1,$t0,$t1
  sw $t0,temp6

  li $v0,10
  syscall

  .data
a: .word 42
lo: .float 5.500000
b: .word 0
c: .float 0.000000
d: .word 0
temp0: .word 30
temp1: .word 10
temp2: .word 30
temp3: .word 10
temp4: .word 0
temp5: .word 2
temp6: .word 0
```

Comment: `b` is an opcode in MIPS assembly; don't use it as a label name.

Comment: Thanks... that's work now